# Rails Indexing: Adding :btree index type to migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, b-tree

I'm trying to figure out how to run a migration that adds the B-Tree index type to an index.

I tried running `rails g migration add_index_to_recipes` which gave me an empty migration:

```
class AddIndexToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
  end
end
```

then I modified the migration like so:

```
class AddIndexToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :recipes, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :recipes, :user_id, using: :btree
  end
end
```

Then I ran `rails db:migrate` but in the schema there is still no index type.
The migration ran fine but my schema still looks like this:

```
create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_recipes_on_user_id"
  end
```

I want it to look like this:

```
create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_recipes_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

Similar questions have been asked here, but so far I've been unable to come up with a solution.

What am I missing?

Comment: You may check this link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/31rd8d/rails_foreign_key_issue_unable_to_migrate/?st=jcm6o4t2&sh=d47ca3f1

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't find anything in that link that helped though.  Maybe I missed something?  I'm not getting any errors...just not seeing the `using: :btree` in my schema.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've already figured this out, but for others finding their way here, this appears to be dropped from the schema generation due to redundancy - https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27981

Hope this helps.